# python - Why is tkinter behaving randomly?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, timing

When I run the below code sometimes the entry has the value I want it to have by default and sometimes it doesn't. each time I run it everything is pretty much the same but the results are different! Someone please help me find what is going on!

**Here is my code:**

```
from settings import Settings
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
settings = Settings(root, "Z:\my files\projects\programing\python\courseAssist\Courses")

parent_directory = Entry(
    root,
    width=60,
    textvariable=settings.parent_directory_var,
    text="Please enter the root directory for all the files and directories to be saved and created in."
)
parent_directory.pack()
mainloop()
```

**And here is the code in the settings file:**

```
from tkinter import *
class Settings:
    def __init__(self, root, parent_directory):
        self.parent_directory_var = StringVar(root, value=parent_directory)
```

Comment: By looking at the GUI window that is opened.

Comment: Oh, OK. sorry, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that _this exact code_ run in the _exact same way_ will sometimes behave differently? That seems  highly unlikely.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to replicate the problem: the entry is completely blank approximately 30% of the time.

Comment: How are you running it? Are you running it from the command line, or from within an environment like IDLE?

Comment: @Kevin: when it's not completely blank, what is in the entry widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley, `Z:\my files\projects\programing\python\courseAssist\Courses`. So it seems like it's either choosing the Settings textvar, or looking at the `text` string, thinking "oops that's not a stringvar, guess I'll ignore it" and consequently displaying nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least part of the problem is the fact that you use `textvariable=...` followed by `text=...`. The `Entry` widget has no `text` attribute; `text` in this context is just a shorthand for `textvariable`. In tkinter, if you specify the same option twice, the last one is used. Thus, your code is the same as `Entry(...,textvariable="Please enter the root...", ...)`.

If your goal with `text="Please enter the root...`" is to create a prompt, you will need to use a `Label` widget in addition to the `Entry` widget. If your goal is to insert that string as the value of the `Entry` widget, you can call the `set` method of the variable (eg: `settings.parent_directory_var.set("Please enter the root...")`).

Also, are you aware that a backslash in a normal string is an escape character? You need to either use a raw string, double backslashes, or forward slashes (yes, forward slashes are valid in windows paths)

For example, all three of these are equivalent:

- `"Z:\\my files\\projects\\programing\\python\\courseAssist\\Courses"`
- `"Z:/my files/projects/programing/python/courseAssist/Courses"`
- `r"Z:\my files\projects\programing\python\courseAssist\Courses"`

Comment: I deleted the text assignment and now it's fixed. tho, I don't think that was the problem bc i added that line after assigning textvariable didn't work and I did it as a shot in the dark thing. And actually I had some other random behaving problem which is also fixed now! And I have no idea what. but I'm happy anyway! the only thing that changed was then my laptop was not plugged in then:))

Comment: And by the way my goal with "Please enter the root..." is for user to know what should be entered and having everything as compact as possible. I know about the escape character, but as far as I know nth will go wrong as long as the character after it is not one of the special characters which in my case aren't. Anyway, it's working as I want and it looks nice:P but thank you so much for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with it, here is my theory:

```
parent_directory = Entry(
    root,
    width=60,
    textvariable=settings.parent_directory_var,
    text="Please enter the root directory for all the files and directories to be saved and created in."
)
```

In the context of the Entry constructor, `text` is merely an abbreviation for `textvariable`. If you specify both for an Entry, it will choose one and ignore the other. I suspect the choice depends on what order the keyword argument dict is iterated over. Perhaps whichever one is iterated over last is the one that gets final say in what the entry uses as its text variable. For most versions of Python, iteration order of dictionaries is not deterministic, so you can expect this to have a different outcome over multiple executions of the same code. (In 3.6 and above, though, the behavior should remain consistent, since dictionary iteration order became consistent in that version)

I suggest resolving this conflict by putting the "Please enter the root directory" text in a separate label widget:

```
root = Tk()
settings = Settings(root, "Z:\my files\projects\programing\python\courseAssist\Courses")

instructions = Label(
    root,
    text = "Please enter the root directory for all the files and directories to be saved and created in."
)
instructions.pack()

parent_directory = Entry(
    root,
    width=60,
    textvariable=settings.parent_directory_var,
)
parent_directory.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't "confuse the engine". That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Sorry, I didn't articulate my thoughts very clearly there. I've edited that section to more concretely lay out what I think is happening: namely, non-deterministic iteration order of dictionaries.

Comment: I think text is seen as short for textvariable. However I did not think that the entry field could use textvariable and thought the correct method would be to do something like `entry.delete(0, END), entry.insert(0, "string")`. So being undocumented doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Mike-SMT, _"I think text is seen as short for textvariable"_. I think that's true, but I think it's an implementation detail that could be subject to change in future versions. _"I did not think that the entry field could use textvariable"_. The `textvariable` keyword is well-documented, so it's fine to use instead of .delete and .insert. _"being undocumented doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist"_ Partially agreed. It certainly exists in the code, or else it would crash with `unknown option '-text'`; but it doesn't exist in the docs, which should give you pause before using it.

Comment: _"Since it's undocumented, it is free to do anything: crash, behave identically to the textvariable keyword argument, make demons fly out of your nose."_ - this statement is false. Tkinter will accept any unique abbreviation of any attribute. It's not whimsical, it has a deterministic behavior. It's documented, but I admit it's not obvious where. I'll try to find where it's documented.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: `textvariable` is a valid and documented attribute of the `Entry` widget. I would argue that it's rarely needed, and you are correct that you can use `.insert` and `.delete`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and @BryanOakley. I have not seen the use of `textvariable` for the `Entry` widget before. Is there any reason to believe that `textvariable` may not work down the road due to the lack of its use and thus should not use it over `insert()` even if it works in the current release, for future proofing the code so to speak?

Comment: _". Is there any reason to believe that textvariable may not work down the road due to the lack of its use"_ - no. There's no lack of use. In fact, I'd argue that almost every example on stackoverflow uses them (unless it's an example I wrote). Most tutorials seem to love using the `textvariable` option with entry widgets. However, I can guarantee that the `textvariable` option will be around for decades to come (mainly because it's been in the language for a couple decades, and tk developers are quite serious about backwards compatibility)

Comment: I discourage `textvariable` because it simply adds one more object that needs to be managed, and doesn't provide any benefit unless you are also putting a trace on the variable (in which case, `textvariable` is invaluable).

Comment: FWIW, the canonical documentation for the acceptance of abbreviated option names is in the tk "option" man page (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/options.htm) where it states: _"Command-line switches may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous."_. In that context, "command-line switches" is what tkinter calls keyword arguments.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thanks for all the info and the link. I will read up on the abbreviation stuff and try to find an example of how textvariable would work with a trace and why you might want to do this. As always Thanks for your invaluable input. Its has helped me immensely in my learning process over this past year.

Comment: @BryanOakley, oh, that's quite interesting. I'm curious what it considers an "abbreviation", since it doesn't seem to be a simple substring check. Playing around with it, it recognizes `textv` and `textvar` and `text`, but not `tex` or `te`, despite the fact that they couldn't be short for anything else. Unless it's comparing to a list of all options, not just supported ones? But then why would `text` refer to `textvariable` and not `text`... Hmm.

Comment: @Kevin: it's just a simple substring check. `te` and `tex` works fine for me. `t` won't work because it's ambiguous (could be `textvariable`, could be `takefocus`

Comment: Might be a version discrepancy since I'm still using 3.5.1. I'm pleased to hear it's behaving sensibly for _someone_ :-)